# How to customize Label on a TextField

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am kind of new in Jetpack Compose and I am trying to customize the label on a TextField, I      want the label to remain on the top of the TextField (like it is always focused) and not to be inside of the TextField.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGqjY.png)

I want it to be like it is on the top and not in the bottom.
Thanks!

```
Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { newText ->
                    text = newText
                },
                label = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Nombre",
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.quicksandregular)),
                    )
                },
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                    cursorColor = azulApp,
                    unfocusedLabelColor = Color.LightGray,
                    focusedLabelColor = azulApp,
                    focusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
                ),
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.quicksandregular)),
                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                ),
                singleLine = true,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
```

I tried the code above with no result.

Comment: It is default behaviour that when ```TextField``` Not focused it will show text and when focused it will move text to top like in attached image. so how do you want your textfield to be?

Answer (score 1):

> I want the label to remain on the top of the TextField (like it is always focused)

If you want to have a `TextField` always focused in Jetpack Compose, you have to use [FocusRequester](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/FocusRequester). So first of all you should declare a variable inside your composable function like this:

```
val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
```

Then inside your `TextField` you have to set the `focusRequester`:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { newText ->
        text = newText
    },
    label = {
        //
    },
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
        //
    ),
    textStyle = TextStyle(
        //
    ),
    singleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester) //
)
```

In the end, right after the `TextField` you have to request the focus as below:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    coroutineContext.job.invokeOnCompletion {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Otrebla. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use **BasicTextField** and add the label with the layout and position of your choice.

```
Column {
        Text( //<--Fixed label 
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
            text = label, 
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .onFocusChanged {
                    if (isFocused && !it.isFocused) onValueChange(text)
                    isFocused = it.isFocused
                },
            value = text,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            singleLine = singleLine,
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge.copy(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground),
            cursorBrush = SolidColor(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
            decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                        .border(
                            1.dp,
                            borderColor,
                            RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                        )
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)

                ) {
                    if (text.isEmpty()) {
                        Text(
                            text = placeholder,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground.copy(alpha = .38f),
                            maxLines = 1,
                            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        )
                    }
                    innerTextField()
                }
            }
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(20.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
        ) {
            if (error) {
                Text(
                    text = errorText,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
                )
            }
        }
```